# Read out a json file php

Tags: php, json

Hi I have this `json` code

```
{"points":[ {"10":"10"}, {"1":"1"} ]}
```

and this is my `php` code

```
$pointsfirst = $row['points'];
$points = json_decode($pointsfirst,true);
$getit = $points['points'][1]['10'];
echo $getit;
```

`$row['points']` is from my database where I have stored the `json`

and I keep getting this error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectg/getpointsapi.php on line 46

what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: `[1]` denoted the second element. The first (having itself an element `10`) would be `$points['points'][0]`

Comment: If you've `print_r($points)` you'll yourself get to know what you were doing wrong over here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way is:

```
$getit = $points['points'][0][10];
echo $getit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$getit = $points['points']['1']['10'];

with the quotas! instead...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in PHP start with offset 0, not 1. This means you should probably use `$getit = $points['points'][0]['10'];` instead.